# How to set sequence for exact consecutive elements of csv string?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a `string` `csv` containing PORTCODE and latitude longitude of location. I use these values to plot the marker on `google map`.

**Eg csv string:**

```
ANC|61.2181:149.9003,   
ANC|61.2181:149.9003,
TLK|62.3209:150.1066,
DNL|63.1148:151.1926,
DNL|63.1148:151.1926,
DNL|63.1148:151.1926,
TLK|62.3209:150.1066,
TLK|62.3209:150.1066,
ALE|60.9543:149.1599
```

i want to autonumber SIMILAR PORTCODE sequence separated with pipe symbol '|' for the PORTCODE which are EXACT Consecutive next element.

**Required out put:**

```
ANC|61.2181:149.9003:1|2,
TLK|62.3209:150.1066:3,
DNL|63.1148:151.1926:4|5|6,
TLK|62.3209:150.1066:7|8,
ALE|60.9543:149.1599:9
```

Any solution using `jquery/javascript/c#` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a neater/shorter way to do this, but here's the <s>first</s> second way that came to mind using JavaScript:

```js
var input = "ANC|61.2181:149.9003,\nANC|61.2181:149.9003,\nTLK|62.3209:150.1066,\nDNL|63.1148:151.1926,\nDNL|63.1148:151.1926,\nDNL|63.1148:151.1926,\nTLK|62.3209:150.1066,\nTLK|62.3209:150.1066,\nALE|60.9543:149.1599";

var output = input.split(",\n").reduce(function(p,c,i,a) {
  if (i === 1) p += ":1";
  return p + (c === a[i-1] ? "|" : ",\n" + c + ":") + (i+1);
});

console.log(output);
```

I've assumed each line ends with a single `\n` character, but obviously you can adjust for `\r` or whatever.

Further reading:

- the [string `.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- the [array `.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like that.

```js
 var csv = 'ANC|61.2181:149.9003,\nANC|61.2181:149.9003,\nTLK|62.3209:150.1066,\nDNL|63.1148:151.1926,\nDNL|63.1148:151.1926,\nDNL|63.1148:151.1926,\nTLK|62.3209:150.1066,\nTLK|62.3209:150.1066,\nALE|60.9543:149.1599'.split(',\n');

//count entry :

var results = [];
var j = -1;
var previous = "";
for (i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
  if (previous === csv[i]) {
    results [j] += '|' + (i+1);
  } else {
    j += 1;
    previous = csv[i];
    results [j] = csv[i] + ':' + (i+1);
  }
}

//And reforme your csv
console.log(results.join(',\n'));
```

Further reading:

- the [string .split() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- the [array .join() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Join)

Comment: easy to understand..! help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

here is C# way to do,

```
public string[] data = { "ANC|61.2181:149.9003", "ANC|61.2181:149.9003", "TLK|62.3209:150.1066", "DNL|63.1148:151.1926", "DNL|63.1148:151.1926", "TLK|62.3209:150.1066", "TLK|62.3209:150.1066", "ALE|60.9543:149.1599", "DNL|63.1148:151.1926" };

int counter = 0;
var output = data.Select(x => new Tuple<string, int>(x, counter++))
           .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
           .Select(h => h.Key + ":"+ string.Join("|", h.Select(x => x.Item2)));
```

output would be `ANC|61.2181:149.9003:0|1,TLK|62.3209:150.1066:2|5|6,DNL|63.1148:151.1926:3|4|8,ALE|60.9543:149.1599:7`

Comment: this is not as per requirement! It must be something like ANC|61.2181:149.9003:0|1,... ans so on notice the colon(:) before setting sequence.but still i appreciate your efforts and your time to help me :)

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE np, simple change the first deliminiter by colon. ans. updated please check

Comment: perfect @A.T. ! :)